# arista pbr - set ip default nexthop

Tags: arista

i have arista 7050s-52 and here is my config :

```
    policy-map type pbr pbr-tun
   10 class pbr-tun-acl
      set nexthop 172.x.x.x

class-map type pbr match-any pbr-tun-acl
   10 match ip access-group pbr-tun-acl
   
   show ip access-lists pbr-tun-acl
Standard IP Access List pbr-tun-acl
        10 permit 4.x.x.0/22
        
        
        interface Vlan84
   description XX
   ip address 4.X.X.X/X
   service-policy type pbr input pbr-tun
```

there is no set IP default next-hop in arista, so I need some of my destinations to use the default route tables and does not use this PBR, so what is the replacement of set IP default next-hop in arista?
Totally PBR is working fine but I am working for some ways that some fo my destinations does not use this pbr and use my default routing table
Thank you.